# Ability to add folders to favorites in Content Manager Explorer (enhancement request)

Tags: cme, sdl-tridion, sites-9.5

feature (creating a folder that resides only under the Favorites shortcut, and when favoriting a folder or content item, sending the item to the favorites sub-folder instead of the favorites root folder) is not available in any current product version. Can it be done as an enhancement for the 9.5 or higher version of Content Manager Explorer?

Here, The requirement is to have the ability to create the folder under the Favorite shortcut and then have the ability to send the pages from different publications to the same folder.

Answer (score 3):

and welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange.

I suspect you'll be better placed checking out Tridion Sites Ideas (https://community.rws.com/ideas/tridion-ideas/i/tridion-sites-ideas) where you can make specific product requests for the consideration of the R&D and Product Managers.

The best use of this forum is more in line with when you have problems setting something up or developing something specific, but you've tried the obvious and want to source specific help on the example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and I have posted the same thing on the rws community